# Difference between importing and declaring module namespace in XQuery?

Tags: xquery

What is the difference between the following:

```
import module namespace fs = "http://expath.org/ns/file";
declare namespace an = "http://zorba.io/annotations";
```

How does "import module namespace" compare to "declare namespace"?

And more over, with namespace decalaration waht is the difference between

```
declare namespace an =  "http://zorba.io/annotations";
```

and

```
module namespace an =  "http://zorba.io/annotations";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The module namespace will allow you to use xquery functions from various modules. This is like using libraries in other languages. For example the functx library:

```
import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com"

functx:substring-before-match('abc-def-ghi', '[dg]')
```

If you would want to create your own module, 'mymodule.xq' you would begin the file with a module declaration:

```
module namespace mymodule = "http://example.org/mymodule";

declare function mymodule:myfunc()....
```

declaring namespaces allows you to create and query xml elements using different namespaces.

For example:

```
declare namespace x="http://some.random.namespace"; 
//x:someelement[. = 'hello world']
```

will query xml elements that have the 'x' namespace.

Now in your case regarding the zorba annotations. Declaring a namespace is really just saying to the xquery processor: this prefix (an) is bound to this namespace (http://zorba.io/annotations). I'm not really sure how to explain it further, it just the way it has been defined in the xquery spec. It's just to tell the xquery processor that if you type:

```
declare %an:nondeterministic function random:random() as xs:integer external;
```

that 'an' is bound to 'http://zorba.io/annotations' which is something that zorba will understand.

You might just as well change 'an' to 'foo':

```
declare namespace foo =  "http://zorba.io/annotations";
declare %foo:nondeterministic function random:random() as xs:integer external;
```

and zorba would still be able to understand it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I get the import module being analogous to using libraries. But I am still a little unsure of what **declare namespace** is doing. I upodated my question with more detail.